# How to reduce number of connections using SQLAlchemy + postgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku, sqlalchemy, flask

I'm developing on **heroku** using their **Postgres** add-on with the Dev plan, which has a connection limit of `20`. I'm new to `python` and this may be trivial, but I find it difficult to abstract the database connection without causing `OperationalError: (OperationalError) FATAL: too many connections for role`.

Currently I have `databeam.py`:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from settings import databaseSettings

class Db(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = Flask(__name__)
        self.app.config.from_object(__name__)
        self.app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', databaseSettings())
        self.db = SQLAlchemy(self.app)

db = Db()
```

And when I'm creating a controller for a page, I do this:

```
import databeam

db = databeam.db
locations = databeam.locations

templateVars = db.db.session.query(locations).filter(locations.parent == 0).order_by(locations.order.asc()).all()
```

This does produce what I want, but slowly and at times causes the error metioned above. Since I come from a `php` background I have a certain mindset of how to deal with DB connections (I.e. like the example above), but I fear it doesn't fit well with `python`.

What is the proper way of abstracting the db connection in one place and then just using the same connection in all imports?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within SQL Alchemy you should be able to create a connection pool. This pool is what the pool size would be for each Dyno. On the Dev and Basic plan since you could have up to 20, you could set this at 20 if you run 1 dyno, 10 if you run 2, etc. To configure your pool you can setup the engine:

```
engine = create_engine('postgresql://me@localhost/mydb',
                   pool_size=20, max_overflow=0)
```

This sets up your db engine with a pool which you pull from automatically then. You can also configure the pool manually, more details on that can be found on the pooling guide of SQL Alchemy - http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/pooling.html

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but I'm having trouble finding this detail and I think you can help. If you set the pool size to 20, doesn't that mean the dyno can only handle 20 simultaneous requests (since each request uses the database, and therefore takes a connection from the pool)? This seems like a huge bottleneck, so surely I'm misunderstanding something. Help!